# Are there research that suggests stock will open higher than average daily value?

Tags: equities

I heard it somewhere that it is an academically documented behavior. I am quite skeptical about it. Are there relevant research that supports it or debunks it?

Comment: The idea I heard a few years ago was that when there are a lot of Day Traders in a stock, they have to exit before the close, banging the closing price down a little. The next morning this distortion is undone and the stock opens slightly higher. I have not read or performed any empirical evaluation of this recently, so it may or may not be there nowadays. In any case it was a tiny effect, impossible to turn into a profit after trading costs (the only implication is: don't day trade).

Comment: After all, Renaissance Technology might have already taken advantage of all market abnormalities.